# How to revert to 10.04

Tags: 12.10

Since "upgrading" to 12.10, the multitude of problems and slowness has  wondering me , if I'm running windows, so I want to take it back to 10.04.
Just some of the problems that we never had in 10.4:
Can't play YouTube and chat at same time;
Can't open more than 5 photos in GIMP without constant grayouts;
Can't easily close apps or programs on desktop;
Can't Use Avidimux and Audacity at same time, CPU load stays at 100%; 
New Gnome is not nearly as intuitive as classic, focus is all over the place, have to constantly switch to have the focus on right window of same program (either browser), etc.
Do I need to wipe my system partition and start over, or is there an easier way to downgrade?

Comment: You know you can use *anything* else other than Unity.. right?

Comment: if ubuntu had a package managing system like GoboLinux, where all different versions of a single package can coexist and some can even be run at the same time (if they dont conflict like writing to the same cfg file of course), we wouldnt be so scared of upgrading things...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot safely downgrade packages in debian-based distros. You may remove and re-install any specific offending package, but this is likely to be a harrowing experience of dependency hell. If you want a complete 10.04 installation, the only good course is to reinstall 10.04.